# Splitting long string without spaces into words with certain length

Tags: python

So I have a really long string from a text document made entirely up of 7-letter words. I need to separate them and store each 7-letter word into an list.

The text document is originally made up of 7-letter words each separated by lines. A small part of it is shown below:
[Screenshot of the text document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKMnJ.png)

After the space is removed it looks like this:
[Screenshot of string with lines removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EayAR.png)
A solution of how to store them in a list straight from the form of being separated in lines would also work for me.

I used this to remove the new lines:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\input.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
print(data)
```

Thanks.

Comment: So are you just after... `words = [line.strip() for line in file]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the split function, which creates a list of tokens based on the provided delimiter. You can provide a '\n' delimiter, something like this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
separated_list = data.split('\n')
print(separated_list)
```

output:

```
['abc', 'def', 'hij']
```

Answer (score 0):

The [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71978699/16823608)is right, but I like to use readlines() with a list comprehension

```py
with open('words.txt') as file:
    data = [word.replace('\n','') for word in file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a new line with a space and then split the whole text to get a list of words

```
data = file.read().replace('\n', ' ').split()
```