# Read a list from file and then split the list into different arrays

Tags: python, list, file

```
Albatrosz Aladin
biologia
9.a
2
Albatrosz Aladin
kemia
9.a
2
Albatrosz Aladin
osztalyfonoki
9.a
1
Antilop Anett
testneveles
9.a
5
Bagoly Barbara
nemet
9.a
3
```

My code:

```
class tan:
    nev = []
    tantargy = []
    osztaly = []
    oraszam = []

    def fel1(self):
        print("1.feladat")
        f = open("/home/i3hunor/Programozas/Info_erettsegi/Erettsegi/2s_2019maj-ideg/Forrasok/4_Tantargyfelosztas/beosztas.txt","r")

        for sor in f:
            tomb = sor.rstrip()

    print(self.nev,"\n",self.tantargy)
```

Expected output:

(self.nev) (in list or any format)

> Albatrosz Aladin,Albatrosz Aladin,Albatrosz Aladin,Antilop
> Anett,Bagoly Barbara

(self.tantargy)

> biologia, kemia, osztalyfoniku, testneveles, nemet

Is it possible to do this? What did i do wrong and why can't I use smt like `tomb[1]`.
Sorry if my question is not understandable, i can't explain it more cause of my lack of english skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the lines, then iterate on them by batch of 4, and save them in the appropriate lists

```
class tan:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nev = []
        self.tantargy = []
        self.osztaly = []
        self.oraszam = []

    def fel1(self):
        with open("test.txt") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
                n, t, os, ora = lines[i:i + 4]
                self.nev.append(n.rstrip())
                self.tantargy.append(t.rstrip())
                self.osztaly.append(os.rstrip())
                self.oraszam.append(ora.rstrip())

t = tan()
t.fel1()  # load data
print(t.nev)
# ['Albatrosz Aladin', 'Albatrosz Aladin', 'Albatrosz Aladin', 'Antilop Anett', 'Bagoly Barbara']
print(t.tantargy)
# ['biologia', 'kemia', 'osztalyfonoki', 'testneveles', 'nemet']
```

Comment: It is working, but i don't understand it neither, sorry, Altough I'm grateful for your time. 
What does this line does? ` n, t, os, ora = lines[i:i + 4]`

Comment: @Lolis4TheWin `lines[i:i + 4]` is a slice of a the list, from index i to i+4, so it contains 4 values, so we can put 4 variable on left and they will receive one element each, try execute `a,b,c,d = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to read a file with tokens separated by new-line, and put them in a list? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71978699/13238310

Comment: I have tried this, it wold be good, but i have to store every item to the dedicated list. And i counldn't find a solution for this, but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to initialize the lists, then read and append the appropriate elements to these lists.

```py
class Tan:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nev = []
        self.tantargy = []
        self.oztaly = []
        self.oraszam = []

    def read(self):
        file = open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

        line = file.readline().replace("\n", "")
        count = 0        

        while line != "":
            if count%4 == 0:
                self.nev.append(line)
            elif count%4 == 1:
                self.tantargy.append(line)
            elif count%4 == 2:
                self.oztaly.append(line)
            else:
                self.oraszam.append(line)
            count += 1
            line = file.readline().replace("\n", "")

        file.close()

    def display(self):
        print(self.nev)
        print(self.tantargy)
        print(self.oztaly)
        print(self.oraszam)

tan = Tan()
tan.read()
tan.display()
```

Comment: It is working but i don't really understand how it is works...
If i 0 mod 4 is 0 why would I append the line to the class? I don't understand why you have to divide it by 4 and if I do it why it is working.
Sorry.
But i really appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. We read one line at a time, and when doing so, we increment the `count` variable. If the `count` variable is a multiple of 4 (`count%4 == 0`) then we add the line to the `nev` list. If `count-1` is a multiple of 4 (`count%4 == 1`) then we add the line to the `tantargy` list. Etc... Thus, you don't "append the line to the class", you append the line to one of the lists, which are attributes of the class.

Comment: AAh  i seee, 
thank you!